# How do i add the css and js in the controller file of Drupal8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

In my controller page i am calling my css. As i forgot to call in info file its not working

```
$build['location_table'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $headers,
  '#rows' => $table_rows,
  '#empty' => t('No data is available'),
  '#attributes' => array(
    'id' => 'docgenr-list-table',
    'width' => '100%',
    'library' =>  array(
            'addmetafeeds/addmetafeeds_creation_css',

        ),
  ),
);
```

My library file:

```
addmetafeeds_creation_css:
    version: 1.x  
        css: 
           theme:   
               css/addmetafeeds_creation.list.css: {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about your question but...

Usually, it's :

```
'#attached' => array(
    'library' => array(
        'addmetafeeds/addmetafeeds_creation_css',
    ),
),
```

and for an example in the library file assuming you want your CSS and JS files...

```
addmetafeeds_creation_css:
    css:
        theme:
            css/addmetafeeds_creation.list.css: {}
    js:
        js/js.js: {}
```

See here : https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer i need.